# React: Uncaught TypeError: Auth.signinSuccess is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, reactjs

Im working on flux arquitecture with react. I have `Auth.js` which exports a function as follows:

```
var Dispatcher = require('Dispatcher');
var ActionTypes = require('ActionTypes');

var Auth = {
    signinSuccess: function(data) {
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
          actionType: ActionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS,
          data: data
        });
    }
};
module.exports = Auth;
```

And then I want to use this function in another script like this:

```
var Auth = require('Auth');

var Main = {
    signIn : function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "a valid url",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
                Auth.signinSuccess(data);
            },
        });
    },
    //More code here
};
```

The url which I made the request is not important. Furthermore, the POST method returns ok the information. The problem is in the line Auth.signinSuccess(data)
which returns 
    Uncaught TypeError: Auth.signinSuccess is not a function

Lastly, the require and exports it is working because it works in another places. Just for a full scenary, this implementations is both with npm and browserify to create a bundle.js with all the code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have syntax errors. Remove extra commas on     var Auth

Comment: Where? I edit to remove the comma... because before the signIn functions I have others, but are irelevant for the case

Comment: @A77ak  you should put `debugger` before `var Main = {` and check what is `Auth` variable at that moment. What is it? Maybe the reason is in cyclic dependency and `Auth` is just an emty object?